# Stop video (native Wordpress player) when Zurb Foundation Reveal is closed

Tags: jquery, wordpress, video, zurb-foundation

I'm using [Reveal from Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/reveal.html) to show a modal box when a button is clicked. When the modal pops up it has a video within it using Wordpress's native video player. If the close button is pressed, the modal disappears but the video continues to play

This is how I'm embedding the video using [Wordpress's native video player](https://codex.wordpress.org/Video_Shortcode):

```
<?php $video = get_sub_field('video_link');
echo do_shortcode("[video src='$video']"); ?>
```

**How can I stop the video when the modal is closed?**

This is my code for some context:

```
<div class="reveal large" id="video-modal-<?php echo $counter; ?>" data-reveal>
    <?php $video = get_sub_field('video_link');
    echo do_shortcode("[video src='$video']"); ?>
    <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>

<a class="button small-clear-button button-<?php echo the_sub_field('colour'); ?>" href="<?php if(get_sub_field('link') != "") { echo the_sub_field('link'); } else { echo "#"; } ?>" <?php if(get_sub_field('video_link') != "") { ?>data-open="video-modal-<?php echo $counter; ?>"<?php } ?>><?php echo the_sub_field('link_text'); ?></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with the [Reveal JS Events](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/reveal.html#js-events), specifically the `closed.zf.reveal`:

> `closed.zf.reveal` Fires when the modal is done closing

And since the WordPress video shortcode renders an [HTML5 Video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video), you can run the [`pause()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/pause) function like so:

```
jQuery(document).on('closed.zf.reveal', '#video-reveal-%', function(event) { // The % is what your PHP prints
    jQuery(this).find('video')[0].pause(): // Looks for a video tag within $this modal
});
```